# Connecting multiple virtual machines to appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, python-appium, appium-desktop

Is it possible to create multiple virtual machine devices (android) in VPS and connect them to Appium!?

I searched a lot on the internet for this topic but didn't find a clear answer

If there is any documentation on how to do this I would appreciate it if you could provide it.